# Como usar correctamennte el patron MVC php y jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy implementando el patrón **MVC** de una manera muy simple, para obtener un mejor orden en mi código.

Estoy desarrollando un sistema con `jquery`, `php` y `mysql`. Todo va bien, hasta que necesito enviar parámetros de una pagina a otra, por lo cual no tengo problema en realizarlo. Lo único es que de la forma que sé hacerlo, estaría rompiendo el **MVC**. Porque desde el `Jquery`, estoy enviando por url variables a una pagina de destino que pertenece a **modelo** en el patrón **mvc**. Entonces ya estaría rompiendo el esquema y volvería con el desorden a mi código.

**Estoy trabajando en una sección de notificaciones**

Fichero **notifications.js** ubicado en *assets/parcel/notifications.js*, que lo llamo desde *views/adm/panel.html*

```
$("#solicitudes").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../model/parcel/despliegue_notifications.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            let despliegueNoti = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = `<div class="header-despliegue" id="header-despliegue"> 
                Notificaciones 
            </div>`;
            despliegueNoti.forEach((recorroDatos) => {
                template += `

                <div class="body-despliegue" id="body-despliegue" 
                    tomoDato="${recorroDatos.id}" >
                    ${recorroDatos.nombre} ha enviado una solicitud para 
                    ${recorroDatos.tipo}
                </div>
                `;
            });
            $("#despliegue-notificacion").html(template);
            mostra_ocultar();
        },
    });
});
$(document).on("click","#body-despliegue", function(){
    let elementoRequerido = $(this)[0];
    let id =$(elementoRequerido).attr("tomoDato");

    $(location).attr('href','../../model/parcel/request-data.php/?id='+id)
})
```

El *model/parcel/request.data.php/*

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        MostrarDatos();
    } else {
        echo "no hay na";
    }
    function MostrarDatos(){
        include('../../control/parcel/db.php');
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reclute where id='$id'";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if(!$result){
            die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        $json = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $json[] = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'nombre' => $row['first_name'],
            'apellido' => $row['last_name'],
            'tipo' => $row['tipo']
            );
        }
        $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
        echo $jsonstring;
    }
```

En **request-data.php** debería mostrar los datos de la consulta. Lo pudiera hacer como lo estoy haciendo, pero rompería el patrón y correría el riesgo de que mi código de vuelva a convertir en espagueti, cosa que no quiero que suceda.

También tengo la opción de trabajar todo en el mismo **panel.html** y seteo todos los `main` a `display:none;` y muestro los elementos que necesito.Pero la idea seria trabajar de manera mas ordenada y mostrar los datos de esas notificaciones en un fichero `html` aparte.

Tienen alguna recomendación para seguir respetando el patrón?

Mi idea era que con `Jquery` método `ajax`. Enviara la variable a otro `html` al ejecutar `$(document).on("click","#body-despliegue"`. y ese `html` solicitara a **request-data.php** de manera automática pero no se me ocurre como.

Les agradecería una orientación o un consejo de como podría solucionar esto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En el codigo que muestras, realmente no tienes "controllers" para hacer tu patron MVC. Lo suyo seria que no llamaras a archivos directamente (como haces en el ajax) sino que llamaras a una url. Tu aplicacion deberia analizar dicha url y redirigir la peticion al controller. De la manera que veo que lo implementas te faltaria un enrutador de controllers.

Comment: Si te interesa tengo implementado MVC del modo siguiente: el Modelo como de costumbre, clases y demás, mapeando los resultados de consultas SQL a ellas con PDO; la Vista como de costumbre,  a ella le paso las salidas, sea HTML, sea JSON, sea XML ... y el Controlador que es donde la cosa cambia un poco en aplicaciones web. Mi Controlador es el archivo `index.php`, al que van dirigidas todas las peticiones con la ayuda de `.htaccess`. Los datos se pasan en la URL y en `index.php` se **controla** lo que debe ocurrir. Por poner un ejemplo: `www.example.com/usuarios/all` ...

Comment: ... en el código programado en el Controlador sabremos por esa URL que se están pidiendo todos los usuarios. Otro ejemplo: `www.example.com/ciudades/1` se entiende que se piden los datos de la ciudad cuyo ID es `1`. En el Controlador debes  diseccionar la URL y determinar qué es lo que se pide. Allí debes también bloquear las peticiones no admitidas (ya sabes, los hackers). Y desde el Controlador (que es el archivo `index.php`) conectas a los otros componentes de tu App.